# Does my Moroccan fiance with Spanish residency need a visa to come with me to visit family in England

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, moroccan-citizens

I am a British citizen with Spanish residency living with my Moroccan fiance who also has Spanish residency, living in Spain.

What is needed in order for us both to visit my family in England for a weeks holiday?

Answer (score 3):

As usual, the source to get the most up to date information is the [UK government's "Check if you need a visa" page](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).

[In your case](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/morocco/tourism/yes), it states:

> ## You’ll usually need a visa to come to the UK
>
> In most cases, you must apply for a Standard Visitor visa.
>
> ## When you might not need a visa
>
> You may be able to apply to come to the UK for free instead of paying for a visa if your partner or family member is a British citizen or from another European country.
>
> ### If your family member is a British citizen
>
> If you’ve been living with your British partner or family member in another European country, you may be able to make a ‘Surinder Singh’ application for a free [family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/surinder-singh). Eligible countries are countries in the EU, Switzerland, Norway, Iceland and Liechtenstein.
>
> #### If your family member is from another European country
>
> You may be able to apply for a free family permit if your partner or family member is from the EU, Switzerland, Norway, Iceland or Liechtenstein. They must have been living in the UK before 1 January 2021.

As far as I understand it, due to Brexit, the first exception is actually no longer possible since 29 March 2022. The second does not apply to you.

So yes, **he will need a visa**.